# How to get quarter for future date using Carbon?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

Simple question: How to get carbon get quarter for future date?
Example: Given datetime: 2023-05-03 14:34:09
I want print which quarter will be using Carbon

Note: `{{ $date->quarter }}` works for 2018-11-04 17:40:05

Comment: I just test it and there is no problem by calling **quarter** on carbon DateTime if is not, can you explain more about your need please, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{{ $date->year .'-Q' . $date->quarter }}
```

gives `2023-Q2`

Comment: ``` {{ $date->quarter }} ```not working for future date

Comment: Absolutely does.  Perhaps you are not parsing future date correctly

Comment: I have table called 'projects' with columns 'start_date' and 'finish_date'. I cast them in Model:
`protected $casts = [
        'start_date' => 'datetime',
        finish_date' => 'datetime',
    ]; `  For start date the 'quarter' is working, but for finish date not! Values can be found in the question body

Comment: tinker: `Psy Shell v0.11.2 (PHP 7.4.28 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> $date = Carbon\Carbon::parse('2023-05-03 14:34:09');
=> Carbon\Carbon @1683124449 {#4056
     date: 2023-05-03 14:34:09.0 UTC (+00:00),
   }
>>> $date->quarter
=> 2
>>> ` --- it works fine.  Check the format of finish date

Comment: Yes it is working thanks, although I had to change variable name to `finish`, removed `date` part. Again if I cast `start_date` and `finish_date` => only `start_date` is instance of Carbon. If I have variable name to `start` and `finish` both of them instance of Carbon now! weird. Laravel 8. PHP 7.4. It

Comment: if you have some time, please try 2 datetime columns, cast them on model. column names should be `start_date` and `finish_date`. I am using Laravel 8. Thanks